# "Series in number" is defined as a sequence of at least two consecutive digits

Tags: c++

"Series in number" is defined as a sequence of at least two consecutive digits.
The function receives a number and returns the number of digit sequences it has.
Example: 123678012 has 3 series (123,678,012)
234608012 has 2 series (234,012)
This is the code I just wrote it adds me for some reason 1 all the time
So I'm stuck thinking why in large numbers he does that and in small ones he does not
For example the number 236 has one series and it works in the code I wrote.
Would appreciate help.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

int countSequeces(int num) {
    int count = 0;
    while (num != 0)
    {
        int last_digit = num % 10;
        num = num / 10;
        int two_last_digit = num % 10;
        if (two_last_digit - last_digit == (-1) && last_digit - two_last_digit == 1)
        {
            count++;
        }
    }
    cout << " number is : " << count;
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    countSequeces(234608012);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you phrase this in the form of a question in the title? I think I found the question but it's missing an object, you stated it as "that". "So I'm stuck thinking why in large numbers he does that and in small ones he does not"

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `234` will count as two series because if the if statement will be true when checking `23`, so `count` gets incremented and will also be true when checking `34` so `count` will get incremented again. You need to make sure you only increment `count` once per series.

One solution to this could look like:

```
bool found_series = false;
if(two_last_digit - last_digit == -1)
{
  if(!found_series)
  {
    count++;
    found_series = true;
  }
}
else
{
  found_series = false;
}
```